# how to send the data to a specific place in a online website using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I want to send the contents of the textarea to  this website , but what I always get is either action not found or the code of the website ..

```
$url = "http://www.browxy.com/";
function get_data($url , $data) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $res =  curl_exec($ch);
  if($res){

      return $res;
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
 curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [this](https://github.com/Vinelab/http)

package to make REST request to an external api, it's easy and simple, on the other side make sure that you have the corrects parameters

Comment: and how  can I do this ?